# How charge custom Li-ion pack 36v 10s6p

Tags: batteries, charger, lithium-ion, diy

I have 10x 6p 18650 batteries. 13AH.
I found a protection [circuit](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/Battery-Protection-BMS-PCB-Board-for-10-Packs-36V-Li-ion-Cell-max-30A-w-Balance-/121442284501?hash=item1c468633d5).
My issue is that I don't know how to charge the batteries. I could use a power source but I got it from my school and it isn't mine. 
They sell for 500+$ so it's out of my budget. 
I couldn't find much information for 2s+ battery pack.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you mean a 10s6p, not 10X?  The lithium ion BMS board that you linked to is for a 10s battery.

Are you building your battery or have you bought it?  If you are building it, then you need to add a balance cable with a JST-XH female connector.

With this, you should be able to charge your battery with its BMS using a number of chargers. One example that comes to mind is the imax 1010B+ charger. You can go to the Imax web site and look at their chargers. They are not cheap, but certainly less than the $300 you quoted above for a power supply. With the imax charger you will get a proper balance charge of your battery using the proper CCCV charge algorithm which you won't get with a straight power supply.

Comment: Thank you very much! In the link provided for the protection circuit, it says voltage limits can be adjusted (per upgrade it says). I asked the seller but he said he didn't know and he needs to get information about it. But it's been a week since that and I doubt I will get my answer. Do you know how the limits can normally be changed? I would like to have 3v min and 4.2v max...

Comment: The battery was at my job, the charger wouldn't charge it. The charger applies 42v then none, 42v then non, etc (even if the voltage is above the minimal limit of 28v for charging)... I decided to scavenge the cells. They were sitting at home for several months and the voltage was sub 2v. I know it's bad but I've had great result charging 6p packs at 0.01A to 28+v and then charging it normally. I made some discharge test and was able to get 90% capacity rating.

Comment: Do you have other charger in mind? The one listed isn't available in US. I live in Canada so even US will end up being quite pricier due to shipping & duty.

Comment: @Lion - I live in Canada too and I bought that exact charger from Hobbyking.  I believe you have to buy it off their international wharehouse, not the U.S. site.  Too bad about the value of the dollar, maybe Trudeau will help.  Hobbyking sells other chargers that would work also, the main problem is that most of them, including the imax, don't usually come with their own power supply, so you have to buy a power supply as well.  I bought a power supply from Hobbyking as well that can run 4 chargers at once for about 50 dollars.

Comment: I have bought a number of those ebay BMS and a lot of them advertise the ability to adjust the max and min voltages through some sort of upgrade, but I have never been able to make that happen.  The seller never seems to be able to help.  I have only have success when the BMS is very expensive and costs more than the battery - not an ebay deal.  This is why a good charger like the imax is so important because you can set max charge voltage per cell on the imax and then the BMS is more of a backup protection in case the charger malfunctions and your not depending solely on an inexpensive BMS.